# How To Obtain IPv4 Address of Oracle DB Server

Tags: oracle

How can I obtain the IPv4 address of my Oracle DB server? I can use SQL plus and use the command: `SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address from dual;`

However this returns me an IPv6 address, I need IPv4.

I have also tried `select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') ipaddr from dual;`

And it actually doesn't return anything, could this indicate anything specific?

Any help would be appreciated guys, thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged for SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you think the server even has an IPv4 address?

Comment: I assume when you google for "Translate IPv6 to IPv4" you should find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need an IP address? There can be "many" of them. For example one interface can be dedicated for backup purposes only. How will you identify that one? Other interface might be dedicated for RAC cluster interconnect and this one might be unreachable for you.

You should search for server's hostname.

```
select * from v$instance;
```